# Resources for learning about multiple-target techniques?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, references

I am looking for resources (books, lecture notes, etc.) about techniques that can handle data that have multiple-targets (Ex: three dependent variable: 2 discrete and 1 continuous).

Does anyone have any resources/knowledge on this? I know that it is possible to use neural networks for this.

Answer (score 10):

**Random forest** handle it rather well, see [Would a Random Forest with multiple outputs be possible/practical?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28968/would-a-random-forest-with-multiple-outputs-be-possible-practical) or [scikit learn's documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html). I guess **GBM** or any tree based method can be adapted in a similar fashion.

More generally, when you run any learning algorithm minimizing a score, you usually work on minimizing $\sum_i(p_i-y_i)^2$ which is one-dimensional. But you can specify any target function. If you were working on (two-dimensional) position prediction, $\sum_i(\hat{y}_i-y_i)^2+(\hat{x}_i-x_i)^2$ would be a good metric.

If you have **mixed type output** (classification and regression) then specifying the target function will probably require you to specify a target function that gives more weight to some targets than other: which scaling do you apply to continuous responses ? Which loss do you apply to miss-classifications?

As for further academic reading,

[SVM Structured Learning's Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_support_vector_machine)

[Simultaneously Leveraging Output and Task
Structures for Multiple-Output Regression](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4501-simultaneously-leveraging-output-and-task-structures-for-multiple-output-regression.pdf)

[The Landmark Selection Method for Multiple Output Prediction](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~lebanon/papers/moplms.pdf)
 (deals with high dimensional dependent variables)

Comment: Given multi-target regression also intends to model the relationships between the Ys, wouldn't you want a loss function that measures the fit of that relationship?

Answer (score 4):

[This paper](http://cig.fi.upm.es/articles/2015/Borchani-2015-WDMKD.pdf) does a good job of describing the current methods, toolkits available, as well as datasets to test on.

I happen to work on a commercial problem requiring multi-target regression, and I found that the [Clus toolkit](http://Clus.sourceforge.net) has a good blend of high performance and robustness

- The documentation is excellent
- The toolkit has several methods for both multi-target classification and regression
- It also support rule-based induction and clustering.
- The ensemble models (Bagging, RandomForest) that I used can be read and interpreted easily.

Some of the newer methods (post 2012) have been implemented as an extension of the Mulan toolkit, here's the [Github link](https://github.com/lefman/mulan-extended). Although these methods such as Random Linear Target Combinations report better performance than ensemble models, I found that the toolkit not as mature as the Clus toolkit and hence didn't use them.

Answer (score 0):

A Bayesian take on this sort of problem: [Bayesian non‐parametric models for spatially indexed data of mixed type](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.1368.pdf). The multiple response element being handled by various normally distributed random vectors and link functions thereof. So that the complete response is a stack of a vector of normals, vector of counts and vector of bernoullis.